# Angular datatable - get current page & Total page

Tags: angularjs, datatable, pagination

I am using Angular Datatable. I need to fetch the current page number and total page number and show it like the below image

[image]

In the below SO link, there is an option provided to use (*in my code, i have used vm instead of scope*)

`$scope.dtInstance.DataTable.page()`

**My Table code in HTML :**

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="itemTable.dtOptions" dt-instance="itemTable.dtInstance" dt-column-defs="itemTable.dtColumnDefs" class="table row-border hover">
```

**Controller Code:**

```
var vm = this;
vm.items = [];
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withPaginationType('full')
.withDisplayLength(10)
.withOption('bFilter', false)
.withDOM('<"top pull-left itemtableInfo"i>rt<"bottom"<"#itemtablePageInfo">p>')
.withLanguage({
"sInfo": '<div><span class="searchDetail">Displaying _TOTAL_ results for <b>\"'+$rootScope.searchValue+'\"</b> </span><span class="searchCount pull-right">Showing _START_ to _END_</span><span class="testDiv">hello</span>',
"processing": "Processing...",
"loadingRecords": "Loading...",
"paginate": {
"first": '<i class="fa fa-backward" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
"last": '<i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
"next": "Next",
"previous": "Previous"
}
});
vm.dtColumnDefs = [
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).notSortable(),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2).notSortable(),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(3),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(4),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(5),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(6).notSortable(),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(7),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(8).notSortable()
];
vm.dtInstance = {};
$resource('./scripts/controllers/data.json').query().$promise.then(function (items) {
    vm.items = items;
});
```

But my dtInstance is always returning me null object and cant retrieve either datatable or page() function in dtInstance.

Below are some of the links i have checked. Looking for some help.
please let me know if anyone has faced similar issues.

1. [Angular DataTable not populating DTInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980618/angular-datatable-not-populating-dtinstance?rq=1)
2. [Paging is reset when data is updated with Angular-DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192577/paging-is-reset-when-data-is-updated-with-angular-datatables)
3. https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/312

Comment: You declare `vm.dtInstance = {}` but try to access `$scope.dtInstance` ..? Please delete the [**first version of the above question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120005/angular-datatable-custom-pagination-info), or this, or both.

Comment: @davidkonrad, in my code i am trying to access dtInstance by 'vm' only. In the SO link it was given as scope. I have modified my question.

Comment: @davidkonrad, i have closed my previous question with the fix i have done. Please help me with "dtInstance" and page number problem.

Comment: how can i get current page number? assume i have navigated to 4th page of table and i want to see page number as 4?

Comment: If you are on page 4, then `vm.dtInstance.DataTable.page()` will return 3.  It is really straight forward.

Comment: @davidkonrad, thanks a lot for your suggestions. I debugged the angular datatable and understood what you were referring. I am able to fix the issue with drawcallback function.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i am able to fix the issue :):)
Below is the code. Please do let me know your suggestions.

```
 vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withPaginationType('full')
                        .withDisplayLength(5)
                        .withOption('bFilter', false)
                        .withOption('drawCallback', function(settings) {
                              if(settings.aoData.length > 0) {
                                var api = this.api();
                                var pgNo = api.page.info();
                                var currPg = pgNo.page;
                                var totalPg = pgNo.pages;
                                // get the label where i need to print the page number details
                                var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#pgNoDetail'));
                                myEl.text('Page '+(currPg + 1)+' of '+totalPg);
                               }
                        })
                       .withDOM('<"top pull-left itemtableInfo"i>rt<"bottom"p>')
                       .withLanguage({
                          "sInfo": '<div><span class="searchDetail">Displaying _TOTAL_ results for <b>\"'+$rootScope.searchValue+'\"</b> </span><span class="searchCount pull-right">Showing _START_ to _END_</span>',
                          "processing": "Processing...",
                          "loadingRecords": "Loading...",
                          "paginate": {
                              "first": '<i class="fa fa-backward" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                              "last": '<i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                              "next": "Next",
                              "previous": "Previous"
                           }

              });
```

Below is the final output.

[image]

~~Suriya